# Ubuntuが起動できません。minimal bash like line editing is supported

Tags: ubuntu

環境はWindows10です。USB2.0にubuntuを入れて持ち運べるようにしたかったので、USBにubuntuのisoファイルを入れて起動して、別のUSB2.0にubuntuをインストロールしました。
その後、再起動したら以下のようなメッセージが表示されます。

```
"minimal bash like line editing is supported"
```

[image: 表示されるメッセージ]

ここからどうすればいいですか？
ちなみに"exit"を入力したら、ubuntuではなくwindowsのほうが起動してしまいます。

PCはNECのVersaProです。

Comment: [Live USB『Ubuntu 18.10』…ライブ起動で設定保存できる！](https://report.hot-cafe.net/ubuntu1810-liveusb-6693) と [設定や変更を保存できる Live USB の作成](https://report.hot-cafe.net/unetbootin-5282#_Live_USB) の組み合わせで Live USB というのを作り直した方が良いようです。

Comment: 上のリンクどおりにやったのですが、保存されませんでした。毎回、最初からになります。

Comment: VersaProはシリーズ名だと思うので細かい型番もあるとよさそうですが、「NEC VersaPro Ubuntu」で検索すると参考になりそうなUbuntuインストール時の躓きとHowToがヒットします。 - [VersaPro (32-bit UEFI) に Linux をインストール](https://researchmap.jp/josqq508b-26434/)

Comment: 仮にUbuntuを起動できたとして、目的が果たせると思えないのですが…

Comment: USBに構築したパーティションの情報をできるだけ細かく追記してください。

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/178073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これはエラーではありませんね。
grubのコンソールが起動されてるので、コマンド操作で Ubuntu をブートできるかもしれません。

具体的には `ls` コマンドで `grub.cfg` ファイルを見つけて、そのファイルを使って grub のメニューを表示させ Ubuntuを起動します。

1. `ls` と 入力すると ディスクと、パーティションの識別名が表示されます。
   `(hdX)` ... Xは整数で 0, 1, 2 という感じのディスクの識別番号です。
   `(hdX,Y)` ... Yはパーティションの識別名です。
2. `ls (hdX,Y)/grub/` と入力して grub.cfg ファイルが見つかるか試してください。
   見つからなければ X , Y を変えて 他のパーティションも試してください。
3. grub.cfgファイルが見つかったら `configfile (hdX,Y)/grub/grub.cfg` と入力します。
   すると Grubメニューが表示されると思います。
4. Enter を押すと Ubuntuの起動が始まります。

なお、機種によって色々なので、これでうまくいかない場合は・・・、同じ機種での成功例を探しみるのが良い気がします。

Answer (score 0):

直接的な回答ではないですが、Ubuntuの持ち運びが必要なら、Ubuntu Tutorialにある手順でBootable USBを作成してはどうでしょうか？

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

BIOS設定も関係するようなので、上記手順だけではすんなりいかないような気がします。こちらのサイトが参考になりませんか？

http://mu60.net/post/145601829674/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%96%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%A7windows-8110-whql